# Hardware Raid Card Reviews with SSDs

Tags: ssd, raid, raid-0, review, hardware-raid

Yes I realize there are several questions about this but none of them seem to have the answer I'm looking for.

I have two SSDs and am looking to buy a purely hardware raid card for them; however, I can't seem to find any reviews that have specifically tested hardware raid cards with SSDs rather than testing the SSDs themselves.

I'm looking for a review because I'm assuming that for example: 100% gain with two 7200rpm drives doesn't necessarily mean 100% gain with a pair of SSDs, since there would be higher speeds, meaning more throughput, meaning more processor/memory usage for the card.

If this assumption is wrong then that's fantastic; however if it's true, I am quite sad and would really appreciate any advice or reviews you can find.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i have worked with, the drives actually do all the work and the board just pairs them togehter, and due to the fact that SSD drives have the same hook ups as a regular SATA drive i dont think you will need to look for a "SSD Raid Card" specificaly, just a good quality Sata raid card should do the trick.

Comment: Not true. Because real RAID controllers abstract the drives as a single "volume" to the system, your RAID controller needs to be able to intelligently support the SSD-only TRiM command to get the best performance and lifetime from your SSD. Controller support for the TRiM command is not well-documented.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently assembled a new PC, and as I need well performing HD's, I decided to go with an SATA-II hardware raid controller in conjunction with OCZ SSD's. The adapter has 128 MB cache on board and in a raid 0 compound, you'll get 800 MB/s read speed as well as 450 MB/s write speed. Adapter wasn't that expensive, found it for around 100€. Together with the HD's it performs more than good.

Same speed will be achieved with RAID 0/1, yet if you plan to go with RAID 0/5 the write speed will be somewhat lower, yet still way over any single SSD drive.

Answer (score 1):

ASUS CROSSHAIR IV does the trick along w/ Windows 7. You might want to check the specs of your board's SATARAID -controller before buying external RAID controllers :

http://vip.asus.com/forum/view.aspx?id=20101224110852910&board_id=1&model=Crosshair+IV+Formula&page=1&SLanguage=en-us

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some reviews about SSDs in RAID setup. One is:

http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/ssd-6gb-raid,2388.html

Also take a look at LSI homepage, there is some material about SSDs in RAID setup. If you have just two disks and need protection against drive failures, then RAID1 is what you need and if you need the best performance possible, then go for RAID0. But keep in mind that error on one disk will cause data loss on both drives.